# recover Xcode project in trash without "put back"

Tags: mac, xcode, data-recovery, trash

I recently deleted by mistake a whole Xcode project (~4000 files) and although the folders were not deleted, the button "put back" from trash is not working. How could I recover my project?
thanks!

Comment: Restore the whole project from your backup?

Answer (score 1):

Undo [Cmd/Z] immediately afterwards might have done it.
Now you're left with manually dragging them back to where they came from. Only files discarded by Finder will have 'Put Back' information.

Comment: `"Only files discarded by Finder will have 'Put Back' information."`  I think that's correct, but you can [*"use"* `Finder` in a script](https://gist.github.com/seamusdemora/1e77817c91ad359af4bd06cd29839a1d), and still get put back option. I love this script - I have it aliased for `rm` in `.zshrc`, and it's come in handy more than once.